# Chainer framework with custom made loss function

Tags: chainer

I am trying to run an old example written in chainer. I am trying to run it either with a Pytorch loss function or preferably with my own custom made loss. The training loss though won't decrease.

I am running the following code by replacing the chainer's in-built loss function softmax_cross_entropy() with a custom made. Although I have included "loss.requires_grad=True" the network doesn't deem to learn. Can anyone help me modify the loss function to Chainer?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from chainer.datasets import mnist
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
# Download the MNIST data if you haven't downloaded it yet
train, test = mnist.get_mnist(withlabel=True, ndim=1)
#_______________________________________________________________________________

from chainer import iterators

# Choose the minibatch size.
batchsize = 128

train_iter = iterators.SerialIterator(train, batchsize)
test_iter = iterators.SerialIterator(test, batchsize,
                                     repeat=False, shuffle=False)
#_______________________________________________________________________________


class CrossEntropyLossManual:
    """
    y0 is the vector with shape (batch_size,C)
    x shape is the same (batch_size), whose entries are integers from 0 to C-1
    """
    def __init__(self, ignore_index=-100) -> None:
        self.ignore_index=ignore_index
    
    def __call__(self, y0, x):
        loss = 0.
        n_batch, n_class = y0.shape
        # print(n_class)
        for y1, x1 in zip(y0, x):
            class_index = int(x1.item())
            if class_index == self.ignore_index:
                n_batch -= 1
                continue
            loss = loss + torch.log(torch.exp(y1[class_index])/(torch.exp(y1).sum()))
        loss = - loss/n_batch
        return loss

def lossfun(x, t):
    loss_fn = CrossEntropyLossManual()
    return loss_fn(torch.Tensor(x.data), torch.Tensor(t.data).long())

class MyNetwork(Chain):

    def __init__(self, n_mid_units=100, n_out=10):
        super(MyNetwork, self).__init__()
        with self.init_scope():
            self.l1 = L.Linear(None, n_mid_units)
            self.l2 = L.Linear(n_mid_units, n_mid_units)
            self.l3 = L.Linear(n_mid_units, n_out)

    def __call__(self, x):
        h = F.relu(self.l1(x))
        h = F.relu(self.l2(h))
        return self.l3(h)

model = MyNetwork()
#_______________________________________________________________________________


from chainer import optimizers

# Choose an optimizer algorithm
optimizer = optimizers.MomentumSGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)

# Give the optimizer a reference to the model so that it
# can locate the model's parameters.
optimizer.setup(model)
#_______________________________________________________________________________


import numpy as np
from chainer.dataset import concat_examples
from chainer.cuda import to_cpu

max_epoch = 10
gpu_id = 0
while train_iter.epoch < max_epoch:

    # ---------- One iteration of the training loop ----------
    train_batch = train_iter.next()
    image_train, target_train = concat_examples(train_batch)

    # Calculate the prediction of the network
    prediction_train = model(image_train)

    # Calculate the loss with softmax_cross_entropy
    loss = lossfun(prediction_train, target_train)
    loss.requires_grad=True
    # Calculate the gradients in the network
    model.cleargrads()
    loss.backward()

    # Update all the trainable paremters
    optimizer.update()
    # --------------------- until here ---------------------

    # Check the validation accuracy of prediction after every epoch
    if train_iter.is_new_epoch:  # If this iteration is the final iteration of the current epoch

        # Display the training loss
        print('epoch:{:02d} train_loss:{:.04f} '.format(
            train_iter.epoch, loss.data), end='')
```